# How map reduce framework can determine to run reduce before map is completely done?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I noticed that usually when hadoop cluster is not busy, before map side is completely done, reduce side starts progressing? How is that possible? I remember reading somewhere that reduce progress indicator is somewhat misleading but can't remember exactly. Can someone shed a light on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

33 <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub>% of any reduce task progress indicator is copying the map outputs.  (Another 33 <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub>% is sorting them, and the last 33 <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub>% constitutes the actual calls to the reduce() method.)  Mappers are finishing up all the time, and as many reduce tasks as you have configured are pulling those outputs as soon as they're ready, so up to <sup>2</sup>/<sub>3</sub> of the first round of the reduce phase will be complete before any reduce() calls happen.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I also was confused about that. By the way, could anybody recommend documentation about that? I've been looking with not many luck.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers already given, this behavior is controlled by the mapred property `mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps`, which represents the percentage (0-1) of map tasks that must be complete before the copy stage commences.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the reducer must copy the map output to the node the reduce task runs. If a map task has finished and committed its output, you can directly transfer it and merge them into the data already available in reducer.

So this will save you alot of time opposed to waiting until all mappers finished.